# What are the transformed crew symbolizing?

Tags: one-piece, symbolism

In episode 644 the crew left on the boat get transformed into some "Artistic things".

What exactly are they symbolising? For brook it was pretty obvious, as it was the screamer. But I couldn't quiet put my finger on the other ones.

[image]

Comment: Brook's transformation resembles Munch's [*The Scream*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scream). Nami and Momonosuke (his head looks like a peach,  which fits with his theme) has Picasso's distinct abstract style. Chopper's face is a distinct cubist style.
The clock on Nami's Sorcery Clima-Tact becomes something that resembles Dali's [*The Persistence of Memory*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Persistence_of_Memory).

Comment: @Krazer why don't you answer questions in answers? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're all a bit based on the arts of Okamoto Taro mixed with some unique traits; like Brook based on the screamer, Nami on some Taro statue, Momonosuke (Samurai Dude xD) based on fantasy, since Momo in Japanese means peach xD, and for Chopper I can't remember xD.

The Sunny also is probably based on Taro arts, as the figurehead is a representation of the Sun Tower of Osaka as you can see here:

[image: Sunny figurehead based on this]

[image]

Comment: oh wow, I was mainly asking about the crew. and totally forgot about the boat! If you could also cover the characters in your answer ill be sure to accept it^^

Comment: Well Nami too seems based on the same author as you can see here http://it.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=212uypx&s=5#.U4TzxPl_t8E While Momonosuke (Momo in Japanese means Peach) Look a bit like a peach infact. So i guess it's a bit on fantasy too, for chopper i can't remember xD

Comment: yeah I found her face to be similar as the statue, but brook/chopper/samurai dude ?

Comment: Told you, they're all a bit based on that author art, mixed with some unique trait, like Brook based on the screamer, Nami same as the sunny author, Momonosuke (Samurai Dude xD) Based on fantasy since Momo in japanese means peach if you see him here http://image.forumfree.it/4/6/0/4/9/9/8/1373389251.jpg you can tell he looks like a peach xD and for chopper i can't remember xD.

Comment: I have edited the Answer ! :)